# React starter template render nothing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script type="text/jsx">
     var x = React.createClass({
        render:function(){
            return (
                <h1>I love react</h1>
            );
        }
     });

     React.render(<x/>,document.getElementById('content'));
    </script>
</body>
```

What's wrong with my reactjs code below? it render nothing. I've included

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.min.js"></script>
```

in the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several mistakes

1. you need include [`ReactDOM`](https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.6.js) and use `ReactDOM.render`, because since version `0.14.*` `.render` method that located in React is deprecated.
2. to define component you should use local variable that starts with an upper-case letter (should be `X` not `x`)
3. instead of `type="text/jsx"` you should use `type="text/babel"` (don't forget include [`babel`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js))

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/28458/)

Answer (score 1):

`<script type="text/jsx">` won't work. This was how old versions did using the old jsx transformer but it's now deprecated.

Use babel instead. [Read more about this topic here.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html)

Also your components' names should always start with a capital letter. `<X />` not `<x />`.